# PHPUnit - implementing abstract method in child

Tags: php, phpunit

I have a set of read-only tests and a couple of ones that modify data (insert/update/delete). I'd like to back up my tables, so each test class would have a list of associated tables that they'll modify. This is just test data.

I thus thought of this:

```
abstract class DataAlteringTestBase extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{

  protected function setUp()
  {
    echo "backing up tables: " . $this->GetAlteredTableNames();
  }

  public abstract function GetAlteredTaleNames();

}
```

One of the subclasses:

```
class DataAlteringTest extends DataAlteringTestBase
{
  function GetAlteredTaleNames()
  {
    return array("some_table");
  }

  public function testDummyStuffChild()
  {
    $this->assertTrue(true);
  }

}
```

The problem is, I think, that PHPUnit tries to get the method implementation from the abstract class, rather than its children.

> Call to undefined method DataAlteringTest::GetAlteredTableNames() -
>   the implementation ...\tests\DataAlteringTestBase.php:6 - the abstract
>   class

How to fix it? or is there something wrong with the idea of implementing this in PHP/PHPUnit in the first place?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was a typo error.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have a few typos - you wrote `GetAlteredTaleNames()` in some places and `GetAlteredTableNames()` in other places.

Comment: Probably better as a comment, wouldn't it? :)

Comment: @yivi, hmm not really, comments are to request clarifications or to suggest improvements to the question, but not to actually answer the question - https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment That being said, I realise that this answer (or the question) won't be of much use to anyone else.

Comment: I know, but as you correctly point out the question is kinda worthless. By answering it we could end up making it harder for the system to correctly delete it in time, or so I thought. Nothing inherently wrong with your answer, of course. Someone else might end up coming here looking for a proper answer and reading about a typo. Uncool.

Comment: Indeed I did. Thx.

Comment: And here we are 3 years later and this question is still here, solely because it has an answer.

Comment: Aren't we making a big deal out of nothing here? In 3 years, there have been 57 viewers for this question, probably most of them in the first few days. Literally 0.05 people per day care about this. The "system" is just fine and can cope with that question.